# onclick get thumbnail url id value

Tags: javascript, string, onclick

hopefully someone can help me.
i want to get a thumbnail id value when an onclick event happens, but no luck, any ideas? thanks

```
<a href="test.ca/images/image-1.jpg?id=1"; onclick="swap(this); getVa(); return false;">this is a small thumbnail image</a>
```

Here is the js for swapping the thumbnail:

```
function swap(image) { 
    document.getElementById("main").src = image.href; 
}
```

now i want to access the id at the end of the thunbnail url. note this url is not a location url. thanks

Comment: Hard to tell what you have to do without some code....

Comment: here is what i have:
<a href="test.ca/images/image-1.jpg?id=1"; onclick="swap(this); getVa(); return false;">this is a small thumbnail image</a> 
here is the js for swapping the thumbnail:
 function swap(image) {
             document.getElementById("main").src = image.href;
         }

now i want to access the id at the end of the thunbnail url. note this url is not a location url. thanks

Comment: Can you put this into your question please? It is hard to read in the comment.

Comment: You can format your code with the *Code Sample* button (looks like `101 010`).

Comment: hi Felix your solution worked, but now how can i display the value on the screen that is already been loaded when i click onclick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`split()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function to get the ID:

```
var url_split = image.href.split('=');
var id = url_split[1];
```

Why are you not using jQuery although you tagged your question this way?

Comment: well i dont have an answer so i tagged whats easier to use. 
i will try your suggestion and see how that goes. thanks again

Comment: Well normally you tag the questions with those tags that belong to your problem. Obviously you don't have a problem with jQuery.

Comment: ok so your suggestion worked. i have few more questions, maybe this will be jquery related. so the id that i get, i want to display it on the page. but the page has already load, so how can i display the value on a page that has already load. i dont want to use alert.

Comment: @Chocho: Reading the documentation of jQuery should help you: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Comment: i actually got it! thanks, i used span id="", etc, etc. i am new to jquery. mayne thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your thumbnail `img`s into anchors and set `rel=<your_id>` to them.
Then in jQuery you can access id via `$('a.myclass').attr('rel')`. So do I, maybe there are other better approaches.

Or maybe you provide some code here?

Comment: here is what i have: <a href="test.ca/images/image-1.jpg?id=1"; onclick="swap(this); getVa(); return false;">this is a small thumbnail image</a> here is the js for swapping the thumbnail: function swap(image) { document.getElementById("main").src = image.href; } now i want to access the id at the end of the thunbnail url. note this url is not a location url. thanks